# Silverstripe Routing is coming up as Page not found

Tags: routes, silverstripe

I have two routes that I'm working on. One of them works and one of them does not. The `UserEducation_Controller` route works fine, but the `UserEmployment_Controller` does not. Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/09xmfhr4

This is what is my routes.yml file:

```
---
Name: userroutes
After: framework/routes#coreroutes
---
Director:
    rules:
        'user/education' : 'UserEducation_Controller',
        'user/employment' : 'UserEmployment_Controller',
        'user' : 'User_Controller'

---
Name: jobroutes
After: framework/routes#coreroutes
---
Director:
   rules:
      'job' : 'JobPosting_Controller'
```

This is my `UserEducation.php` file:

```
class UserEducation_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'add', 
        'edit' => '->isOwner', 
        'remove' => '->isOwner', 
        'UserEducationForm', 
        'doAdd'
    );

    private static $url_handlers = array('edit/$ID' => 'index', 'add' => 'index');

    // INSERT NEW EDUCATION ENTRY
    public function index()
    {
        $backUrl = $this->request->getVar('BackURL');

        // If register success
        if( $this->request->getVar('success') == 1 )
        {
            // Form submission was successful so redirect to BackURL
            return $this->redirect( $backUrl );
        }

        return $this->renderWith(array('UserEducation', 'Page'));
    }
}
```

This is my `UserEmployment.php` file:

```
class UserEmployment_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'add', 
        'edit' => '->isOwner', 
        'remove' => '->isOwner', 
        'UserEmploymentForm', 
        'doAdd'
    );

    private static $url_handlers = array('edit/$ID' => 'index', 'add' => 'index');

    // INSERT NEW EMPLOYMENT ENTRY
    public function index()
    {
        Requirements::css('themes/simple/datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.css');

        $backUrl = $this->request->getVar('BackURL');

        // If register success
        if( $this->request->getVar('success') == 1 )
        {
            // Form submission was successful so redirect to BackURL
            return $this->redirect( $backUrl );
        }

        return $this->renderWith(array('UserEmployment', 'Page'));
    }
}
```

I tried switching the placement of the routes so the employment one comes first and then didn't change anything. The result is the same (education works, employment does not).
I created a public function `init()` method in my employment and did a `die()` statement in there and that didn't even hit so I'm guessing it's not even hitting the controller.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I even tried putting useremployment instead of user/employment to see if it was the nesting causing the problem and it still wouldn't work when I navigated to mysite.com/useremployment/add. I did the same with the usereducation and it still worked fine.. did a flush and dev/build.

Comment: You can call a controller directly with its name. So does a call to mysite.com/UserEmployment_Controller work at least? And i noticed the indentation of you yml config is with 4 spaces, normally you only need 2 spaces

Comment: No calling the controller doesn't work. The UserEducation_Controller works fine though.. strange.. why is it not recognizing my controller? I did a class_exists('UserEmployment_Controller') and it returned true... So it knows it's there, but it doesn't.

Comment: Double check the filename for typo.. It has to be the same like the Controller (maybe without _Controller suffix). Otherwise SilverStripe's autoloader doesn't find it.

Comment: Try reordering the items in the yml, I've seen strange results with that